# Interpreting AIC forward stepwise function in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, aic, stepwise-regression

My homework asks me to:

"Try a forward stepwise procedure with entry probability of 0.20. Then describe the model that is arrived at and whether it might be preferred."

I used the forward step function, starting off with a null model. Which is as below:

[image]

I am confused as to how to interpret this:

1. What does the specific AIC values (87.08, 54.46 etc) mean?
2. How is it related to p-values? Is entry probability referring to p-values?
3. If AIC is not related to p-values, how can I interpret my model based on entry probability on R?

Comment: This is homework, so please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Have you read about the [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)? Is there some particular statistical software that your instructor uses for "forward stepwise procedure with entry probability of 0.20"? Some software uses p-values for deciding whether to include a variable, but `step` in R does not. Do you understand the limits of stepwise selection, and how poorly the results tend to generalize to other samples from the same population?